# dom.storage.enabled in Tor Browser 4.0.2. Security problem?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, windows, deanonymization

According to http://ip-check.info/?lang=en dom.storage.enabled is on and this is a problem. The site recommends it to change to false. Is this a security problem?

Is this a wrong setting of 4.0.2? Will you fix it in the next update? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I could not replicate your result in Tor Browser 4.0.6. That suggests that either the initial result was incorrect (i.e., the the website provided incorrect information about DOM storage, or else that a problem that did exist in Tor Browser 4.0.2 has now been corrected.

Potential exploits get exploited almost as soon as they become known but the dangers that they pose are dramatically reduced by ensuring that you are using the latest Tor Browser version.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [TBB 4.5](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-45-released), you can configure the level of security using a simple slider. This especially applies to JS settings.

Using the highest setting, IP check does not complain about enabled DOM storage.